# Proof on area sum relationship of convex polygon

Tags: triangles, recreational-mathematics

Assign to each side b of a convex polygon P the maximum area of a triangle that has b as a side and is contained in P. Show that the sum of the areas assigned to the sides of P is at least twice the area of P?

Comment: Any thoughts about the question?

Comment: Nothing much really I tried a few ways but the didn't work

Comment: This is problem #6 from IMO 2006. See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h101488p572824). (or you can visit IMO official site to look for official solution)